# Can I use the free space on an NTFS Hard Drive to make a "Mac OS Journaled" partition to use as a backup space?

Tags: partition, ntfs, hfs+

I have a 1 TB NTFS HDD which has 350GB free space, how would I format that 350GB to use it as a backup space for my MacBook?

`diskutil list` output:

```
/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:               Windows_NTFS ADATA HD710             1.0 TB     disk1s1
```

Comment: Is the 350 GB partitioned separately or a part of a single drive??

Comment: Not partitioned just a single one.

Comment: Unless you create a separate partition you can't format the drive, as it will remove the rest of the data as well. The only option you can use it, copy the data on a temporary drive, make a partition, copy back the data, and then use it as a Back up drive for time machine.

Comment: Seems like there's no way to keep the data on the ntfs part untouched, Actually the whole goal is to use my hdd to backup my macbook, is there any way to use a ntfs hdd to do that? or formating is neccessary?!

Comment: OS X by default have Read-Only state for NTFS, so for creating a backup drive you need to format it to Mac OS Journaled

Comment: With assumption of having Tuxera NTFS installed which gives ability to read/write, can you suggest a way?

Comment: @klanomath free space imagine a 1tb hdd with 350gb free space and not partitioned at all.

Comment: Most likely the disk has a single NTFS formatted partition. To determine how much the partition can be shrunk and to actually shrink the partition would require a computer running a Windows operating system.

Comment: @klanomath let's not getting deep into this, but it's allocated, I can put information from the disk here just tell me mac disk utility info or ...

Comment: The instructions under Windows is given [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731894.aspx)

Comment: @klanomath here is: http://pastebin.com/L1BpEn0B

Comment: @DavidAnderson So you mean i have to make an extra partition on Windows for my drive then format it in Mac ? Is it possible for allocated space?

Comment: You need windows to shrink the NTFS partition. Windows or OS X can create the new partition. You need OS X to format the new partition.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Rest of the data on the drive would be untouched?

Comment: Windows will not delete any of the files on the NTFS partition. It just creates empty space at the end of the disk. You then add a new partition and format this any way you want.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I found GParted for doing this on Mac because i do not have access to a Windows machine, I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you've already got **GParted**, use ´GParted /dev/disk1´ to resize your NTFS partition.  It has a nice Graphical front-end, and just in case you need it, here is the [manual](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dman-page).
2. As David Anderson said a couple times, above, then you can open the OSX application *Disk Utility,* which is under /Applications/Utilities, and then you will see empty space on that disk:
3. Create a partition of the type HFS+ (journaled), and you'll be ready to use it as your *Time Machine* disk.

I think you'll be finished in no time, since you personally already found Gparted, and sound like you have good information about this.  You would also be able to do this all on the command-line is OSX with ***diskutil.***

Comment: I finally done that, But the easiest way to backup on a NTFS Drive is using CCC(Carbon Copy Cloner) along with it's amazing settings.

Comment: Did you use the gparted live CD?  or it sounded before like you had actually a port of parted/gparted... I'd like to clarify my answer for the future then.

Comment: @wertvoll thanks for the tip on CCC; excellent name! ...if that is the best answer, maybe write it up as your own answer, or check the above one as "solved."